# Show icons in WPF application that supports zooming

Tags: wpf, icons, zooming

My WPF application supports zooming. When I show icons on a canvas, and I zoom in, all the shapes, text, etc. are shown correctly, but the icons are shown pixelelated.

What is the correct way to show icons?

I was thinking about building the icons in a vectorial format, and then convert them to XAML?

- Is this the correct way?
- How should I proceed?
- Could you please give an example about how to use it?

Comment: you thinking is right you shoud go with vector based graphics for this kind of situations.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ScaleTransform` on your icons like.

```
var st = (ScaleTransform)image.RenderTransform;
double zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? .2 : -.2;
st.ScaleX += zoom;
st.ScaleY += zoom;
```

Comment: The image will be shown blurry using this technique, since the images are pixel-based images!!

Comment: yes that will. because the your icons are in Pixals thats why i commented to use vectorbased images.